# onfocus onblur not working properly?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using two Javascript functions, but they seem to not be working correctly when using `input` `onfocus` and `onblur`

Heres what I have:

**HTML**

```
<form class="nav" method="post" action="action.php?do=search">
    <input id="sb" class="search_bar" type="text" name="search_input" value="Search" onfocus="removeValue()" onblur"showValue()" />
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
var sb = document.getElementById("sb").value()

function removeValue() {
    if(sb=="Search") {
        sb="";
    }
    else {}
}
function showValue() {
    if(sb="") {
        sb="Search";
    }
    else {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `=` on `onblur "showValue()"` it should be like `onblur="showValue()"`

And also
`var sb = document.getElementById("sb").value;` should be inside the funciton eg:-

```
function removeValue() {
  var sb = document.getElementById("sb").value;
  .......
  .......

function showValue() {
    var sb = document.getElementById("sb").value;
    .........
    .........
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the elements value inside the `onblur` and `onfocus` functions. The variable you currently have defined takes the value at run time, it's not a reference:

```
function removeValue() {
    var sb = document.getElementById("sb")
    if(sb.value=="Search") {
        sb.value="";
    }
    else {}
}

function showValue() {
    var sb = document.getElementById("sb")
    if(sb.value="") {
        sb.value="Search";
    }
    else {}
}
```

I would just make a variable of the element, and then call `.value` when you want to set and check it.

Comment: Thanks, works nicely - just an issue with onblur() now... and I've fixed the HTML typo

Answer (score 0):

There's no such function `value` on the input field, so replace this:

```
var sb = document.getElementById("sb").value();
```

with this:

```
var sb = document.getElementById("sb").value;
```